# Deploying Go App

Tags: deployment, go

I have a REST API endpoint written in Go and I am wondering what is the best way to deploy it. I know that using Google App Engine would probably make my life easier in terms of deployment. But, suppose that I want to deploy this on AWS. What options/process/procedures do I have. What are some of the best practices out there? Do I need to write my own task to build, SCP and run it?

One option that I am interested in trying is using Fabric to create deployment tasks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just got back from [Mountain West DevOps](http://mtnwestdevops.com) today where we talked about this, a *lot*. (Not for Go specifically, but in general.)

To be concise, all I can say is: it depends.

For a simple application that doesn't receive high use, you might just manually spin up an instance, plop the binary onto it, run it, and then you're done. (You can cross-compile your Go binary if you're not developing on the production platform.)

For slightly more automation, you might write a Python script that uploads and runs the latest binary to an EC2 instance for you (using boto/ssh).

Even though Go programs are usually pretty safe (especially if you [test](http://goconvey.co)), for more reliability, you might daemonize the binary (make it a service) so that it will run again if it crashes for some reason.

For even more autonomy, use a CI utility like Jenkins or Travis. These can be configured to run deployment scripts automatically when you commit code to a certain branch or apply tags.

For more powerful automation, you can take it up another notch and use tools like [Packer](http://packer.io) or [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/). I'd start with Packer unless your needs are really intense. The Packer developer talked about it today and it looks simple and powerful. Chef serves several enterprises, but might be overkill for you.

Here's the short of it: the basic idea with Go programs is that you just need to copy the binary onto the production server and run it. It's that simple. How you automate that or do it reliably is up to you, depending on your needs and preferred workflow.

Further reading: http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1r0q79/pushing_and_building_code_to_production/ and specifically: https://medium.com/p/528af8ee1a58